# Using jQuery as a command line on a saved DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is something along the lines of what I'd like to do,

```
web_page = fetch("http://www.google.com")
console.log($(web_page).find("body"))
```

via a simple command line. So in a nutshell, save a webpage and then query that page using jQuery.

Are there any tools like this available?

Comment: You can't do it cross-browser without first jumping through some fiery hoops, though you could just go to that page and open your debugging console and load jQuery.

Comment: hm. I'm thinking this would be more of "browser-less"? since I want to do it via command line.... or maybe even without jQuery, but just using pure JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try phantomjs , a headless webkit solution

http://phantomjs.org/

Comment: Indeed, the general term for this is "headless browser". There are headless versions of Firefox available as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re willing to do this in a browser, try using YQL or your own proxy to get around cross domain ajax issues, fetch the remote page via ajax and then traverse the response.

F.ex using something like https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax/

You can do

```
$.get('http://google.com', function(html) {
    console.log( $(html).find('body') );
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uc7vt/

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with Node.js,
`npm install jquery`